# Why am I getting "write queue file: No space left on device" from postfix when there's 5GB of free space on disk?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix

It started happening today... all of a sudden, no apparent reason!

Here's the output from df:

```
assp:~# df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs             6291456   1378384   4913072  22% /
tmpfs                  8202680         0   8202680   0% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                  8202680         0   8202680   0% /dev/shm

assp:~# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs           55781934   83005 55698929    1% /
tmpfs                2050670       2 2050668    1% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                2050670       1 2050669    1% /dev/shm

assp:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs            6.0G  1.4G  4.7G  22% /
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Here's an actual entry from /var/log/mail.warn:

```
Dec 11 17:55:37 assp postfix/smtpd[30614]: warning: not enough free space in mail queue: 0 bytes < 1.5*message size limit
Dec 11 17:55:37 assp postfix/cleanup[30617]: warning: 4361D850D54: write queue file: No space left on device
```

.

Comment: Please paste the output of df here?

Comment: How about the actual log lines, plus anything around them that could be related?

Comment: Are there any large files which are held open by running or Zombie processes?  `lsof` might be of some help here

Comment: How about the output of `postconf -n` ?  Also, maybe, `du -sh /` ?

Answer (score 6):

You might want to run a `df-i` to see if you have used up all your [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

You can have available storage space, and not have the ability to add files.

```
cache:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             132G   68G   58G  55% /
cache:~# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            17514496 13543293 3971203   78% /
```

You also might want to check to see if you have any quotas set (`repquota -va`).

Comment: df -i shows only 1% of max inodes used. repquota -va shows no quotas in effect.

Answer (score 3):

5% (iirc) of space is reserved for root, might be your filesystem is "full" for normal users.
You can get more info with e.g.

> tune2fs -l /dev/sda1

Comment: server has only 6.2GB total... 78% free.

Comment: This helped me out! Thanks. The entry to look at is `Reserved block count` and multiply it by `Block size` to get bytes reserved.

Answer (score 1):

Which device is full?  Perhaps there's plenty of space on one partition, but another (e.g. /tmp) is full?  Do a `df -h` and see if any of the partitions are close to full, and then figure out if postfix uses that partition.

Comment: None of the partitions actually are full... That's what so strange about the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but is your queue > 2GB in size? I'm wondering if it's running into a filesystem size limit or a hard limit for postfix. I know that Apache dies when it hits 2GB on the log file (or at least it did at one point)

Comment: What do you mean by that? "is your queue > 2GB in size"

Comment: I meant your mail queue. In case something went haywire and created a single file larger than 2GB, in which case maybe something died while trying to parse it. 2GB has been a historic limit for several programs, even when the filesystem itself supports larger files just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of message_size_limit which is set?

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#queue_minfree is a possible cause for this response.

Comment: I don't have message_size_limit, queue_minfree, or mailbox_size_limit.
None of them are set in main.cf

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg07849.html

> Postfix tries to avoid the situation where the system is 100% full
>   and it can no longer get work done.
>
> To completely avoid such conditions, Postfix would have to reserve
>   an amount of space the size of (message size limit * inbound
>   concurrency). Unfortunately, this is not practical in many cases,
>   so it settles for 1.5 times the message size limit.

This means that although you've got 5GB free - your settings are such that you need more.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on OpenVZ virtual machine. Space is temporarily taken by backup.