# "Write Error: No space left on device" when df displays 60% of free space?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, df

It's been happening for the last few weeks in a small unix server (it doesn't have all standard unix commands, just the basics included in the BusyBox package) that I was configuring to backup files.

If we check the free space of the server it shows:

```
 Filesystem             |   Size  |    Used | Available | Use%| Mounted on
 /dev/hdc2              | 678.4G  |  416.6G |   261.8G  | 61% | /tmp/mnt/D
 /dev/sda1              |  96.1G  |   36.0G |    55.2G  | 40% | /tmp/mnt/USB/USB_C
```

Now I am trying to copy either a 700MB files to USB_C or a 90GB files to `/tmp/mnt/D` where I can see that there's plenty of space available, however, I keep on receiving the followin error:

```
cp: Write Error: No space left on device
```

Any idea what the problem could be and how it could be fixed?

As mentioned, this is a small unix server with the bare minimum of unix commands, so most of the commands mentioned in other posts do NOT work for this box. Hence that I might need the help of someone who knows what I could try in this specific system to give us some clue...

Comment: Did you look at any of the other 158 questions which show up when searching for `No space left on device`?

Comment: Have you tested that your filesystems are ok? Try to run a fsck on both filesystems (you may need to umount them first) and then check again available space

Comment: Thanks @NuTTyX, I'll try to have a look and see if that one gives some info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gut reaction says **inodes**

Check your inodes. Those are the hidden part of the filesystem that keeps metadata about the files.

```
df -i
```

I suspect you may have many, many small files. If that's the case -- and note that each file needs an inode -- you can use up inodes before you use up actual storage space.

Comment: This unix version doesn't have many options. For `df` I've just got:

    df: illegal option -- i

    BusyBox v1.90-JKR (2008.04.28-13:21 CET) multi-call binary

    Options:

        -h      print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 243M 2G )
        -m      print sizes in megabytes
        -k      print sizes in kilobytes(default)

Comment: I just looked at the other linked "possible duplicate" and that one has everything I'd ever be able to post. Here it is again, please review this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/93606/why-am-i-getting-write-queue-file-no-space-left-on-device-from-postfix-when-t

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/find-where-inodes-are-being-used this question shows how to use tune2fs in place of "df" for checking inodes (about 60% of the way through under "checking inodes") - we are all assuming ext filesystems here - please do confirm that!

Comment: I managed to see the free inodes with 'tune2fs'. It turned out that I had like 90 million of free inodes, so not sure what was causing this problem. 

I tried running fsck quite a lot of times, and although it seemed that it was doing and repairing something, it was always displaying the same kind of error messages when I run the command again. 

I ended up copying the data to an external HDD, formatting the partition , putting the data back, and now I'm able to use the available space.

I still don't know what was causing the problem in the 1st place though. Marking it as fixed with REFORMAT