# Postfix warning: not enough free space in mail queue

Tags: linux, postfix, docker, xfs, glusterfs

I have already checked the solutions at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/93606/why-am-i-getting-write-queue-file-no-space-left-on-device-from-postfix-when-t), but I can't find the reason.

This is my situation:

- Running postfix inside a docker container (docker swarm).
- Docker container has no quota.
- `/var/mail` volume mounted from `/mnt/shared/postfix/var/mail/` in host.
- `/mnt/shared/` is a network logical device using glusterfs (xfs formatted) with 3 nodes.

```
# df -h

Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2         20G   12G  7.1G  62% /
/dev/vda2         20G   12G  7.1G  62% /var/spool/postfix
/dev/vda3         60G   31G   30G  51% /gluster
mx1:shared       120G   63G   58G  52% /mnt/shared

# df -i

Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda2        1310720 200164  1110556   16% /
/dev/vda2        1310720 200164  1110556   16% /var/spool/postfix
/dev/vda3       31455744 523000 30932744    2% /gluster
mx1:shared      31455744 523000 30932744    2% /mnt/shared

# df -k

Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2        20466256  8816788  10584508  46% /
/dev/vda2        20466256  8816788  10584508  46% /var/spool/postfix
/dev/vda3        62880772 32043020  30837752  51% /gluster
manager1:shared 125761544 65343656  60417888  52% /mnt/shared

# gluster volume status shared detail

Status of volume: shared
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick mx1:/gluster/brick
TCP Port             : 59830               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 727880              
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/vda3           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 29.4GB              
Total Disk Space     : 60.0GB              
Inode Count          : 31455744            
Free Inodes          : 30932804            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick mx2:/gluster/brick
TCP Port             : 55380               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 3784930             
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/vda3           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 29.4GB              
Total Disk Space     : 60.0GB              
Inode Count          : 31455744            
Free Inodes          : 30932804            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick mx3:/gluster/brick
TCP Port             : 58943               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 3905147             
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/vda3           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 29.4GB              
Total Disk Space     : 60.0GB              
Inode Count          : 31455744            
Free Inodes          : 30932804

# gluster volume status shared inode

Brick : mx1:/gluster/brick
Connection 1:
LRU limit     : 16384
Active Inodes : 958
LRU Inodes    : 16383
Purge Inodes  : 0
----------------------------------------------
Brick : mx2:/gluster/brick
Connection 1:
LRU limit     : 16384
Active Inodes : 829
LRU Inodes    : 16373
Purge Inodes  : 0
----------------------------------------------
Brick : mx3:/gluster/brick
Connection 1:
LRU limit     : 16384
Active Inodes : 1087
LRU Inodes    : 16370
Purge Inodes  : 0

# postconf -n

Most relevant:

mailbox_size_limit = 100000000  
message_size_limit = 50000000   

Full config:

alias_database = texthash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = texthash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 10m
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 3.6
content_filter = smtp-amavis:amavis:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/config/header_checks.regex
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 100000000
maillog_file = /var/log/mail.log
maximal_backoff_time = 10m
maximal_queue_lifetime = 10m
message_size_limit = 50000000
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/config/my.networks.plain
myorigin = $myhostname
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/config/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/config/dnsbl_reply
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11] b.barracudacentral.org psbl.surriel.com bl.spamcop.net bl.spameatingmonkey.net dnsbl.sorbs.net swl.spamhaus.org*-2 list.dnswl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].0*-2, list.dnswl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].1*-4, list.dnswl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].[2..3]*-6
postscreen_greet_action = drop
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
queue_run_delay = 5m
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXPORT, LOW, MD5, aDSS, kECDHe, kECDHr, kDHd, kDHr, SEED, IDEA, RC2, RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_loglevel = $smtpd_tls_loglevel
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = $smtpd_tls_protocols
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = $smtpd_tls_protocols
smtp_tls_security_level = $smtpd_tls_security_level
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access texthash:/etc/postfix/config/client_access.hash permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_pipelining permit_sasl_authenticated permit
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_invalid_helo_hostname permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient check_recipient_access texthash:/etc/postfix/config/recipient_access.hash check_sender_access texthash:/etc/postfix/config/sender_access.hash permit_sasl_authenticated check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf warn_if_reject reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination warn_if_reject reject_unverified_recipient reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org=127.0.1.[2..99] reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org=127.0.1.[2..99] reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org=127.0.1.[2..99] warn_if_reject reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org=127.255.255.[1..255] permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = inet:dovecot:999
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.users.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access texthash:/etc/postfix/config/sender_access.hash permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_non_fqdn_sender permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = ${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = ${config_directory}/dh512.pem
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = EXPORT, LOW, MD5, SEED, IDEA, RC2, RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = $smtpd_tls_protocols
smtpd_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/config/transport.hash
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.aliases.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql.users.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

The error looks like:

```
warning: not enough free space in mail queue: 0 bytes < 1.5*message size limit
94AA9C30D6: to=<info@mail.example.com>, orig_to=<info@example.com>, relay=amavis[10.0.5.92]:10024, delay=376, delays=371/0/0/5.3, dsn=4.3.1, status=deferred (host amavis[10.0.5.92] said: 452 4.3.1 id=97454-19 - Temporary MTA failure on relaying, from MTA(smtp:[postfix]:10025): 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

The mail queue is practically empty (reported by mailq)

The free space reported by postfix gradually decreased until it reached 0. Where does that value comes from? Is there any way to get the total free space "seen" by postfix?

Ultimately I restarted the server and I'm not seeing those warnings/errors anymore. However I suspect the problem will be back soon or later. I don't want keep restarting the server each time, so I would like to know why is that happening.

Comment: Show `df /var/spool/mqueue` from within the container running `postfix`.

Comment: There is no `/var/spool/mqueue` but `/var/spool/postfix` which is mounted by postfix I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /var/mail volume mounted from /mnt/shared/postfix/var/mail/ in host

But the default director for the mailq is /var/spool/postfix. Map this in your dockerfile (or create a new directory in /mnt/shared/postfix/var/mail/ then symlink it from the /var/spool/postfix in the docker root volume, or change the 'queue_directory' setting in main.cf). Make sure you carry over any permissions and you should be sorted.

Comment: I have updated my question. As you can see `/var/spool/postfix` is automatically mounted in `/` by postfix. I created a directory in the host root partition (not the shared partition) and created a docker bind to `/var/spool/postfix`. `df` reports exactly the same output from within the container.  Although I don't understand the reason, for now it seems the problem was solved (I had to wait 2 days to be sure). Thank you.